# Is there a way to update the design of an old Microsoft Access Database to a newer version?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have an old Access database that has fallen to me to maintain and update. Currently all of the design of the forms is using a previous versions of Access' UI Form design and I'm wondering if there is a quick way to update all of these to the newer versions UI Form design. I realise this is purely cosmetic but I think some of the users react badly to it just because it looks old, regardless of how it operates. Thanks

Comment: *a quick way to update*. You mean update the format and controls of a form? Nope, no quick way, you would need to change each one, or use autoformat options

Comment: No, indeed not if you wish to replace menus (CommandBars) with ribbon equivalents.

Comment: There is the DB options setting **Use Windows-themed Controls on Forms**  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/set-user-options-for-the-current-database-29b6b7be-4c3b-43a7-b8f0-5e1c68f5adce#__toc309288140 -- you can try that and see if it changes anything, and if you prefer it.

Comment: I'd start with editing each form and changing the background color to something "new"?  - then change the look of the main menu a bit.   If that works, then you are done!